# MVC4 WebAPI not compressing GET responses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gzip, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-compression

I'm working on a project that uses the MVC4 WebAPI (RC). The responses are not gzip compressed (dynamic compression in IIS is enabled).

The responses from normal MVC controllers are compressed. Do I need a specific setting to enable gzip compression for WebAPI responses?

I could add a custom compression handler, but if possible, I would just like to use the built-in IIS compression.

BTW, I know this is almost a duplicate of [Compress HTTP GET Response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10443588/317440), however the accepted answer there doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Is dynamic compression enabled for mimetype 'application/json; charset=utf-8'? By default this is not enabled even if dynamic compression is enabled

Comment: @EivindT how can I check that?

Comment: You can look in the applicationhost.config file under %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config in the <httpCompression><dynamicTypes> section. You should not edit the file, instead use appcmd.exe to change it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375645/243936

Comment: Cool, that works! If you'll post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is dynamic compression enabled for mimetype `application/json; charset=utf-8`? By default this is not enabled even if dynamic compression is enabled.

To see if it is enabled, you can look in the `applicationhost.config` file under `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config` in the  section.

You should not edit the file, instead use `appcmd.exe` to change it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375645/243936

Comment: I had no problem editing the applicationhost.config file manually using notepad.  All you need to add is one line to the httpCompression -> dynamicTypes section: `<add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />`.  See this link for more details: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-web-api-compression  Once I did that, my web api responses were gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can install a nuget package to achieve that, this requires little configuration, in client side you just need to add the accept-encoding:gzip.

Using this approach is better these days when ASP.Net is able to run in any Web Server.

In this video I have a full / complete explanation of WebApi using gzip compression. Is in spanish, but you know "Code is an universal language"

[NinjaTip #16 | Incluyendo soporte para GZip en WebAPI | C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI-ZMLCoaLc) 
[image: NinjaTip #16 | Incluyendo soporte para GZip en WebAPI]