# Change 'allowDefinition' and 'overrideModeDefault' in applicationHost.config programmatically

Tags: iis-7.5, appcmd

I'm looking for a way to edit `allowDefinition` and `overrideModeDefault` values of the section `system.webServer/httpCompression` to `Everywhere` and `Allow`, but I need to do this programmatically as it will be part of our deployment process.

I tried to use the `unlock` command of `appcmd.exe`, but this changed nothing in my applicationHost.config file.

My goal is to change this value as part of our deployment process to our Azure web application, so we can more easy change the httpCompression values within our web.config file.

Comment: Have you read this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775261/how-to-enable-gzip-http-compression-on-windows-azure-dynamic-content/7375645#7375645