# Enabling gzip compression per-endpoint in Service Fabric Service

Tags: c#, gzip, azure-service-fabric

Our application uses Service Fabric as its backbone and our microservices are Service Fabric Services. After running some auditing using Lighthouse on the front-end, I saw that the recommendation to `enable text based compression` was listed and began investigating how I can add `gzip` to some of my responses.

For our Node server, I simply added the `compression` middleware and used it.

For other services, I went inside of the `Web.config` and added the following:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>

<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add enabled="true"  mimeType="application/json"/>
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add enabled="true"  mimeType="application/json"/>
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Upon reloading my web app, I did notice that the responses were now coming in compressed, but I do not want to necessarily compress all responses.

When I setup any of my endpoints, I follow the following format:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{customer}/items")]
[Authorize]
public Task<ItemsModel> Get()
{
    return _itemsService.GetAsync();
}
```

Is there a way to enable compression on a per-endpoint basis instead of per-service?

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775261/how-to-enable-gzip-http-compression-on-windows-azure-dynamic-content

Comment: The c# code can read the configuration settings and determine which responses are using GZIP.

Comment: Does this doc about urlcompression help maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/urlcompression

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process;

1. Edit your ServiceDefinition.csdef file to contain this in the WebRole tag:

> `<Startup>
>     <Task commandLine="EnableCompression.cmd" executionContext="elevated" 
>      taskType="simple"></Task>
>   </Startup>`

2. In your web-role, create a text file and save it as “EnableCompression.cmd”
3. EnableCompression.cmd should contain this:

   `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:True /commit:apphost
       %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost`

This simple process will enable dynamic compression for the json returned by the web-role in Azure.

Source:https://cloudmonix.com/blog/how-to-enable-gzip-http-compression-on-windows-azure-endpoint/

You can see also these:

https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D56A00000RbtbBSAR/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-mobile-fabric

https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/2a58dd

[How to enable gzip HTTP compression on Windows Azure dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775261/how-to-enable-gzip-http-compression-on-windows-azure-dynamic-content)